# Keeping clients timer in sync - TCP

Tags: networking, synchronization

I have a flash game using TCP sockets that connects to a C/Linux server. The game is very basic. There are almost no ways for clients to cheat as the game is mostly a text based game with some graphics.

**The syncing timer problem:**

The game has a timer that needs to be identical for each client (ex. starting at 60 seconds and counting down to 0). I have thought of some basic technique where the server enforces the timer for each client such as sending the server time to each client every second, but this could be a large drain on the server and a lot of bandwidth usage. I'm hoping someone can give me some pointers to a synchronisation technique that will be minimal on bandwidth and server processing time.

I'm thinking this solution may have to do with using the client's clock. I don't think a lag spike would effect the user clock, but there may be something I'm overlooking here that could jeopardise the integrity of the game.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)?  That's what "Windows, Network Time" and Linux uses.

Comment: NTP is a new concept to me. I'm going to check it out. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: From what I'm reading NTP might be overkill for me. It seems to only be UDP and require it's own server. I simply need an implementation that could have all users start a countdown with their own clock and make sure that they don't fall out of sync by more than a second.

Comment: In fact flash is TCP only, so I'm not even sure if NTP is possible.

Comment: Couldn't a client just ask the server 'wake me up in x seconds'?

Comment: i think if the server enforces an absolute timer and ignores any requests beyond that time it may work? I'm new to real time networking and there probably will be some "gotyas" that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

You must think about which will affect the monitor result, like netwalk-delay.
Generally, you need the simulation on both client and server. Client is called Client-side prediction and sync the server's simulation be fixed your client.
You need recording your gameobject's state by input and collision by moment-chance.
Send these message and add a delay time to run your game-logic, the "delay time" can guarantee 
other player's sync on simular time by run the game logic.

It's difficult walk to box2d's sync on TCP. I suggest you to use P2P.